# Multilingual site in sharepoint server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, multilingual

I want to create a multilingual site in sharepoint with one language as English and other language as Arabic. Now I my feeling I will have to use two master pages one for Arabic and other for English.


Now my question is , is it possible to have two masterpages or is there any other solution that I cap opt for.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create multiple master page, rather you have to SharePoint Multilingual Site feature. following thing you get with it:

- Create, manage, and read content in different languages.
- Navigate a site in a preferred language.
- Collaborate with people in different regions, in different languages,
  in the same application.
- Manage personal sites by using a preferred language.
- Search and browse content across a company by using a preferred
  language.

read more about it: [Plan for multilingual sites in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-for-multilingual-sites) and also read this: [Create a multi-language website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6?ocmsassetID=HA102886546&CTT=1&CorrelationId=4aa713e9-ec67-4d67-8937-f994dca78c43&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

one of the main requirement is, you have to install the desired language pack on all [SharePoint servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-for-the-multilingual-user-interface).